# Find matched string in an object that contains mutiple arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have an object that contains multiple arrays of strings, like

```
const object = {
    "arrayA": [
        "A1",
        "A2"
    ]
    "arrayB": [
        "B1",
        "B2"
    ]
    ...
}
```

How can I use Javascript function or lodash to find if a given string exists in the object? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), get the list of arrays
- Using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), iterate over this list to check if any array has the string using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const checkForString = (obj = {}, str) =>
  Object.values(obj).some(arr => arr.includes(str));

const object = { "arrayA": [ "A1", "A2" ], "arrayB": [ "B1", "B2" ] };

console.log( checkForString(object, "A1") );
console.log( checkForString(object, "B1") );
console.log( checkForString(object, "C1") );
```

Comment: Helps a lot. Thanks